# style text input and submit button as inline

Tags: html, css, input, submit, textinput

I would like to ask you for a hint, how to style my text input and submit button that will be inline, especially - my pattern looks [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/patterncf.jpg/):

And the reality [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/541/realityw.jpg/)

In code I have:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/home/index" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  </div> 
  <input class="search" data-autocomplete="/home/autocomplete_produkties_nazev" id="name" name="nazev" type="text" value="" /> 
  <input src="/images/search_btn.jpg?1308243954" type="image" /> 
</form>
```

And in CSS:

```
input.search {
    padding: 6px;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 15px;

    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    background-image: url('/images/xxx.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 61px;
}
```

I am trying to get and how to repair, that the submit button is always above than text-input button... I don't know, where could be a problem... could be someone give me some tips or hint, how to place on the same line text-input and submit button?

Thank you

Comment: put all the inputs inside the div then give it a width. you use float: left for the inputs

Comment: Try validating before you ask for styling!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but I believe what you're looking for is display: inline-block; which can be added to both elements and will put them on the same line in the order that they are written in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try floating the search input left and the submit button right: http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/FEQhb/1/